# Suggestions on how to deal with a MacBook Pro that cannot be turned on

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, battery, hardware

I bought a MacBook Pro 2016 in 2016. It served me very well for almost 4 years. Last year I suddenly couldn't turn it on. Tried everything on Apple's website but still didn't work. After about two weeks I tried it again and it worked again. Since then, I also noticed that the battery didn't work like before: It quickly drops to less than 85 percent even if I don't use it.

In April 2021, I couldn't turn it on again. Again, I tried everything suggested by Apple and it didn't work. I waited and tried again, it still didn't work.

Finally I went to an Apple store. A staff examined it and told me that the battery had changed shape and there's also a problem with the logic board. He suggested that I pay about $600 for a fix (changing the battery and the logic board, and also changing the keyboard). I thought it would be too expensive, so I left with the broken MacBook.

So here I am, with a MacBook Pro that cannot be turned on. On the one hand, I don't want to spend too much money to fix it (after all, the new M1 MacBook Air costs less than $1000 now). On the other hand, I still need to at least wipe the hard drive before I get rid of it. The nice thing is that I encrypted the whole hard drive before.

Any advice on how I should go forward? Should I find some third-party fixers or should I simply return it to Apple without getting a penny?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? If it's broken & will cost 600 to fix, you may as well throw it in the recycle. If the drive is encrypted, no-one's going to get into it… so what solution are you looking for?

Comment: 3rd party repair can be less expensive than Apple. But it will still cost you something. The good ones will repair the System Board not replace it. They will replace the battery and the top shell w/keyboard.  The MBP is 5 years old which is the typical replacement age. An M1 MacBook Air will in many ways be faster and better than the 2016 MBP at most tasks.  Depends on if you will be pushing it hard for extended periods of time. The M1 MacBook Pro includes an active cooling fan while the Air does not. It won't throttle as much. The Air is cheaper than what you paid 5 years ago.

Comment: I'd like to add that macOS 12 Monterey will have some features only available to M1 Macs, so that may be a good argument for getting a new one.